# Google App Engine's Blobstore is applicable to 30 seconds request timeout?

Tags: google-app-engine, timeout, blobstore

Google App Engine imposes a 30 seconds timeout for every request. Is this applicable when uploading to the blobstore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Even with regular requests to your app, the 30 second limit only applies to time your application spends processing requests.  The timer does not include time the server takes to receive the request nor time spent sending the response back to the user.